# Im building an app with nativescript and I need to accept RECURRING payments. How?

Tags: nativescript

I'm building an app with nativescript and I need to accept recurring payments somehow. What strategies/solutions are there? 
Is this possible:
A user who wants to sign up for a subscription clicks a button inside my app. The user is directed to an external third party web page (stripe? ayden?). Somehow the payment & invoice details are sent along automatically. After the payment is done he is redirected back into my app (cant see how that is possible though). Somehow a token is received in my app. After a month my app is automatically calling some api of the payment provider (stripe? ayden?) and sends the token and gets a status back whether he paid or not. Invoicing is all done by the payment provider. 
Is this all possible? I'm newbie here. I want to avoid to have to build some backend solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's possible to do recurring payments. You must decide whether you are going to use in-app purchase Or third party payment gateways.

You must have to use in-app purchase if the payment is being made to use any premium features of your app. You may use third party payment gateways if it's for a different purpose.

If you choose to go with a third party then you must decide which one it is. There are plugins for Stripe and you always have an option to directly access any third party from your project if there is no ready made plugin. Generally recurring payment requests should be handled by your backend, you may have a corn job that runs every certain period and process the payments for the users those who have opted for a subscription.

Also you must think of sending emails upfront to your users saying that you are going to charge them for so and so purpose, have an option to cancel it etc., So you would definitely need a solid back-end system.